# why cumtrapz integrator always return zero?

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to use cumtrapz function to integrate velocity at a given time interval to get the position. However, it keeps giving me zero position at the beginning and end of the iteration, which is not what I expect.
Can anyone help? 
Thank you

Comment: Would be easier if you provide the data and your script/

Comment: `it keeps giving me zero position at the beginning and end of the iteration` - It only returns one value, the cumulative integral, so I don't understand what you mean when you say it gives you zero at the beginning and end. As @FooTheBar mentioned, it would be helpful to see your code.

Comment: The interval can be divided into n and integrate along that sampling time gives the integral for that particular interval.